# How can I use `eslint-config-airbnb` in a non-react project?

Tags: reactjs, eslint, eslint-config-airbnb

I am using `eslint` in my project and I'd like to use `airbnb` style. The problem I have is I need to install `eslint-config-airbnb` dependency which depends on `eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y` and some `react` plugin. My project is not a react project and I wonder how I can use `airbnb` eslint without bring react dependencies.

Below is the configuration in my `eslint` to use `airbnb` style:

```
extends: [airbnb, eslint:recommended]
```

Comment: copy paste the config and remove react-specific things

Comment: there is no react specific things in my project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Airbnb ships a separate package [`eslint-config-airbnb-base`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-config-airbnb-base) (which `eslint-config-airbnb` inherits from) that contains just the base styles without React/JSX support.